# Second activity does not load in login form

Tags: android-activity

I created a simple app of login form but it did not go to second activity after login. There is no error in the code. Will you please help me, here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText Name;
    private EditText Password;
    private TextView Info;
    private Button Login;
    private int counter=5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validate(Name.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void validate(String userName, String userPasswor) {
        if ((userName == "admin") && (userPasswor == "1234")) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            counter--;
            Info.setText("No of Attempts Remaining: " + String.valueOf(counter));
            if (counter == 0) {
                Login.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `equals` to compare strings, not `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write your code

```
if((userName =="admin")  && (userPasswor=="1234"))
    {
        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

change this code as

```
if((userName.equals("admin"))  && (userPasswor.equals("1234")))
    {
        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

also enter Second activity in Android.mainfeast file.